# Retrieve PHP data on separate text block in window Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, php, mysql, xaml

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = sqli_query($con,$query);

while(cvt=sqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $cvt['name'];
    echo $cvt['age'];
    echo $cvt['blood_group'];
    echo ",";
}
```

PHP file which show information about user. It works correctly.

This is my Windows Phone 8.1 C# function which retrieves this data from PHP file.

```
 public async void sndandrec(string feedingaddress, HttpResponseMessage     response, TextBlock  tblock, HttpClient myhttpClient, int work)
        {
            try
            {
                response = await myhttpClient.GetAsync(resourceUri);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Need to convert int HResult to hex string
                tblock.Text = "Error = " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") +
                "  Message: " + ex.Message;
                responseText = "";
            }
            tblock.Text = response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase;

            tblock.Text = responseText.ToString();
        }
```

This function also works correctly. It show the response from PHP file in `tblock.Text`.

The problem is that all the text are show in one text block. Is there a way to show the name,age and block group in separate text block.

The response from the above file is

```
adam23B+,david30AB+ .......
```

I want to separate them like

```
Nametexbock:adma
Agetextblock:23
BlockGptextblock:B+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use json_encode to pass data from one application to another

Replace this code

```
while(cvt=sqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $cvt['name'];
echo $cvt['age'];
echo $cvt['blood_group'];
echo ",";
}
```

with

```
while(cvt=sqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$d[] = array('Nametexbock'=>$cvt['name'],'Agetextblock'=>$cvt['age'],'BlockGptextblock'=>$cvt['blood_group'])
  }
echo json_encode($d);
```

Comment: Thankx For the answer @Ajeet Kumar. Do you know any good article show me how to retrieve that json data in Windows Phone 8.1 App?

Comment: Plz Answer to this Post [Click to go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673314/show-json-data-obtained-from-php-file-in-windows-phone-8-1)