# Show Json Data obtained from PHP File in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, php, json, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have PHP file which gives me following JSON:

```
{"Name":"Waqas","Age":37,"Address":"Kanju"}
```

When I execute this method in Windows Phone it gives me the same JSON:

```
{"Name":"Waqas","Age":37,"Address":"Kanju"}
```

in textblock named `tblock.Text`;

This is my method for receiving data from PHP file in JSON format:

```
public async void sndandrec(string feedingaddress, HttpResponseMessage   response, TextBlock tblock, HttpClient myhttpClient)
 string responseText;
            tblock.Text = "Waiting for response ...";
          try
        {
            response = await myhttpClient.GetAsync(resourceUri);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Need to convert int HResult to hex string
            tblock.Text = "Error = " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") +
                "  Message: " + ex.Message;
            responseText = "";
        }
       tblock.Text = response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase;

       tblock.Text = responseText.ToString();
```

This is my class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Address { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to show the `Name` value in `TextboxName`, similary `Age` value in `TextboxAge` and `Address` value in `TextboxAddress`. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Start reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, major edit, and I basically removed all of my last answer because of it being incorrect.

Reference a JSON library, the easiest is to search for JSON.NET on NuGet and reference that. Then you can make a call to your server and parse the JSON data.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://addresstojson.com/json.json");
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

using(var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(stream.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Then you can still set the textblocks with the data retrieved using your RootObject class you defined in your question

```
tbName.Text = "Name: " + json.Name;
tbAge.Text = "Age: " + json.Age;
tbAddress.Text = "Address: " + json.Address;
```

Here is the JSON I used for this example:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 25,
    "Address": "Mars"
}
```

Comment: using System.Web.Script.Serialization;  is not recognized in Windows Phone 8.1,

Comment: Did you add a reference to the web extensions like I mentioned?

Comment: I think i should Use <Code >  DataContactJsonSerializer </Code> which is in using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

Comment: I've never developed for WP8+ so I wouldn't know if the assembly was there. I'll drum up a quick app and see

Comment: If You can do it Using System.Runtime.Serializtion.Json  . THen Please Help i tried this but the syntax is wrong ` var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(myCars,responseText);`

Comment: I used this NameSpace when JSON file is in comptuer memory. and it works but in case of respose from PHP file. Not getting it right ..

Comment: Okay, just refer to my answer again. This solution worked for me.

Comment: Thanx you Very Much. you have change the Direction of My Work.i was working with `Windows.Web.Http` But this is all `System.net`  But any who it works thanks Again.

Comment: Welcome. I find System.Net a lot easier to work with as far as network calls and such are concerned